# Merge 2 columns in dataframe by prioritize one of them

Tags: r, merge

Assuming that I have the following data.frame:

```
Value1    Value2
   'a'      <NA>
  <NA>       'b'
  <NA>       'c'
   'd'       'e'
   'f'       'g'
  <NA>      <NA>
```

How can I compine these columns in one by saying that the first column has the 'priority', meaning that if both columns have value chouse from the first one. SO the result should be:

```
Value3
    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
    'd'
    'f'
   <NA>
```

edit: where `<NA>` are not available values.

Comment: Are these real `NA`s as if I do `is.na(df)` R will recognize them?

Comment: `ifelse(!is.na(d$Value1), d$Value1, d$Value2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple method using `max.col` (I'm assuming these are real `NA`s)

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(!is.na(df), ties.method = "first"))]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "f" NA
```

If these aren't real `NA`s, you could do

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df != "<NA>", ties.method = "first"))]
```

Or alternatively convert them to `NA`s using `is.na(df) <- df == "<NA>"` and then try the first solution.

Comment: I guess akruns `ifelse` solution is simpler. This solution is more general in a sense that it doesn't matter how many columsn you have, it will always work with the same code while giving preference to the first column.

Answer (score 3):

We can try `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  If there is `NA` value in 'Value1', we assign the 'Value2' elements to 'Value1', remove the 'Value2' column and change the column name to 'Value3'.

```
library(data.table)
setnames(setDT(df1)[is.na(Value1), Value1:= Value2
              ][, Value2:= NULL], 'Value3')
df1
#   Value3
#1:      a
#2:      b
#3:      c
#4:      d
#5:      f
#6:     NA
```

---

Another popular way would be `ifelse`

```
with(df1, ifelse(is.na(Value1), Value2, Value1))
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "f" NA
```